# Sharepoint 2013 - Text styles not visible for multiline Field

Tags: 2013, list, custom

I created a Teamsite with template STS#0. In that teamsite I have a custom list where I added a new column of type 'Multiple lines of text'. 
Only Page elements are visible in the styles on the ribbon. The Text Styles are not visible. (As shown on the Image)
[image: Only Page Elements]

What could be the reason of this behavior?

Thanks in advance for the answers